# Dynamic appending of the textarea elements with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a drop-down list with some options. Multiple options can be selected at once. When some options are selected the corresponding hidden divs are shown.

Now I need to dynamically add a `textarea` to the shown divs - not to all of them. If an option is deselected the corresponding div is hidden and the added textarea input must be removed from it. How can I do that?

```js
$("#dist").change(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  if (optionValue) {
    $(".dist-box").hide();
    for (var k in optionValue) {
      $('div.' + optionValue[k]).show();
    }
  } else {
    $(".dist-box").hide();
  }
}).change();
```

```css
.dist-box {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dist[]" id="dist" class="dist" multiple="">
  <option value="dih">dih</option>
  <option value="vii">vii</option>
  <option value="des">des</option>
</select>

<div id="dih" name="dih" class="dih dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>

<div id="vii" name="vii" class="vii dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
</div>

<div id="des" name="des" class="des dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3tm7b0r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you need you can hide all the `.dist-box` elements when a change is made, then use the selected values from the `select` to build a selector string to target the required ones, before appending the textarea to them and displaying them:

```js
$("#dist").change(function() {
  $('.dist-box').hide().find('textarea').remove();
  if (!this.value)
    return;
    
  let idSelector = $(this).val().map(v => `#${v}`).join(',');
  $(idSelector).append(function() {
    return `<textarea name="${this.id}"></textarea>`
  }).show();
}).change();
```

```css
.dist-box {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dist[]" id="dist" class="dist" multiple="">
  <option value="dih">dih</option>
  <option value="vii">vii</option>
  <option value="des">des</option>
</select>

<div id="dih" class="dih dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>

<div id="vii" class="vii dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
</div>

<div id="des" class="des dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
</div>
```

That being said, the dynamic appending of the `textarea` elements seems almost entirely redundant, as the `textarea` are always present when the parent `.dist-box` is visible, so you could just leave them present in the DOM but hidden along with the parent.

Comment: My list is a relatively big one and it is a part of a more big form. Because only some options will be selected at the same time and not all textareas will contain a text, I don't want to save to the database the rest of them, because they will be saved if I will add textareas to the `.dist-box`. Probably I can solve this in a some other way, but for now I am happy with your solution. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: I found a small inconvenience: all added textareas will have the same name. I don't mentioned this, but I need them to have the name of parent divs (will be the same as `id`).

Answer (score 1):

You can consider making a minor modification in your code - Instead of adding the change functionality on the parent, add it to the child as follows:

```js
$("#dist option").click(function(){
    let optionValue = $(this).val();
    let isSelected = $(this).is(':selected');

    let currentBox = $('div.' + optionValue);
    
    if(isSelected){
      /* $(".dist-box").hide() */;
      currentBox.append('<textarea class="ta"></textarea>');
      currentBox.show();
    } else{
      currentBox.find('.ta').remove();
      currentBox.hide();
    }
}).change();
```

```css
.dist-box { color: #fff; padding-top: 10px; display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dist[]" id="dist" class="dist" multiple="">
    <option value="dih">dih</option>
    <option value="vii">vii</option>
    <option value="des">des</option>
</select>

<div id="dih" class="dih dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>

<div id="vii" class="vii dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. 
</div>

<div id="des" class="des dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
    Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a textarea with a different id or name attribute inside the parent div of each paragraph.

```js
$("#dist").change(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  if (optionValue) {
    $(".dist-box").hide();
    for (var k in optionValue) {
      $('div.' + optionValue[k]).show();
    }
  } else {
    $(".dist-box").hide();
  }
}).change();
```

```css
.dist-box {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

textarea {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dist[]" id="dist" class="dist" multiple="">
  <option value="dih">dih</option>
  <option value="vii">vii</option>
  <option value="des">des</option>
</select>

<div id="dih" class="dih dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
  <textarea id="dih-textarea"> </textarea>
</div>

<div id="vii" class="vii dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
  <textarea id="vii-textarea"> </textarea>
</div>

<div id="des" class="des dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>
  <textarea id="des-textarea"> </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to dynamically add a textarea to the shown divs - not to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

To add the textarea, create a "render" function and add it to your loop. Also, make sure to remove all previously added textareas at the start of the loop. See the example:

```js
$("#dist").change(function(){
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    if(optionValue){
        $(".dist-box").hide();
        $(".ta").remove();
        for(var k in optionValue){
            $('div.' + optionValue[k]).show();
            renderTextarea(optionValue[k]);
        }
    } else{
        $(".dist-box").hide();
    }
}).change();

function renderTextarea(id) {
    let markup = '<textarea class="ta"></textarea>';
    $(`#${id}.dist-box`).append(markup);
}
```

```css
.dist-box { color: #fff; padding-top: 10px; display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dist[]" id="dist" class="dist" multiple="">
    <option value="dih">dih</option>
    <option value="vii">vii</option>
    <option value="des">des</option>
</select>

<div id="dih" class="dih dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>

<div id="vii" class="vii dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
    Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. 
</div>

<div id="des" class="des dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
    Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. 
</div>
```