# Store the content of the dynamic added textarea elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have [a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64195730/1354580) of dynamic appending of the `textarea` elements with jQuery, thanks to Rory McCrossan. Maybe the dynamic appending of the textarea elements is almost entirely redundant, but I have my reasons for this. The working scenario is next: the user selects one or more options from a drop-down list and for each option a corresponding DIV section is displayed and, consecutively, a `textarea` is dynamically added to that section. If an option is unselected the DIV is hidden and the textarea is removed. But exists here an inconvenience: if an user added some text to a dynamic appended textarea and after this he/she decided to select an additional option, unselecting or not others, the previously added text is lost. How this previously added text can be retained along with the corresponding selected option/textarea when user selects an additional option?

Here is the discussed solution:

```js
$("#dist").change(function() {
  $('.dist-box').hide().find('textarea').remove();
  if (!this.value)
    return;

  let idSelector = $(this).val().map(v => `#${v}`).join(',');
  $(idSelector).append(function() {
    return `<textarea name="${this.id}"></textarea>`
  }).show();
}).change();
```

```css
.dist-box {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dist[]" id="dist" class="dist" multiple="">
  <option value="dih">dih</option>
  <option value="vii">vii</option>
  <option value="des">des</option>
</select>

<div id="dih" class="dih dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>

<div id="vii" class="vii dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
</div>

<div id="des" class="des dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
</div>
```

Comment: So this is clear. If I select and item and enter text, then select a different item this removes the textarea for the first. If I reselect the first, you want my text to be retained?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, this was the problem (but not the textarea, only the content of the textarea was removed). Thank you for solving it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by storing the contents of the textarea in a `data` property on its parent div. And restoring it when you add back in  the textarea.

```js
$("#dist").change(function() {
  $('.dist-box').each(function() {
    $(this).data('val',$('textarea',this).val());
    $(this).hide().find('textarea').remove();
  })
  
  if (!this.value)
    return;

  let idSelector = $(this).val().map(v => `#${v}`).join(',');
  $(idSelector).append(function() {
    return `<textarea name="${this.id}">${$(this).data('val') || ""}</textarea>`
  }).show();
}).change();
```

```css
.dist-box {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dist[]" id="dist" class="dist" multiple="">
  <option value="dih">dih</option>
  <option value="vii">vii</option>
  <option value="des">des</option>
</select>

<div id="dih" class="dih dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>

<div id="vii" class="vii dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
</div>

<div id="des" class="des dist-box" style="color: initial; display: none;">
  Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
</div>
```

Comment: Works very well! Thank you very much!